# Strange gap between divs on iOS

Tags: ios, css, html

I have two divs with 0px space between, but on iOS devices there's a strange very thin gap.
Please see http://melino.com once in your desktop browser and once on your iOS device. Note the thin line behind the logo on the top left.

Is there a fix for that?

Here's a preview on mobile Safari:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/previewios.png/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure - but maybe mobile Safari doesn't understand

```
margin: 0 77px;
```

correctly (#header-logo-box).

Did you try to write all margin values? Like:

```
margin: 0 0 0 77px;
```